# Query multi lingual city names + calculating radius from coordinates Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

In a database I have users, listed with their address data. On the site there's a searchbar a visitor can enter a cityname to search for users (using Google Maps API). The coordinates of the user are also stored in the database.

There are actually two things I would like to figure out:

1. How to calculate the coordinates from the origin coordiante (specific address of the user) + a radius of 1, 5, 10, x.. km. 
   *Goal is to query the database for rows with coordinates within the given radius from certain coordinates.*
2. The site is multi lingual, if I enter a name in English, is there a way to query to Google to get that cityname in other languages? 
   *Goal is to find matches in Berlin (German/English for the capital of Germany) when a visitor enters e.g. Berlijn (Dutch for Berlin).*

I've been browsing Google's docs regarding the places, geocode, maps but without any usable results so far.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "Geocoding", an address is always in the local language, but I think that for names of countries or even cities you can use several languages.

[Here is the geocoding tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes)

Answer (score 0):

Answering 2. first you can use PHP function [SOUNDEX()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) to create a new field(column) on name.
Answering 1. Use the [Haversine Formula](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe#MySQL%5D%5B2%5D) to find places within a given radius.
The query below uses this formula.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT  name, latitude, longditude( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longditude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM gb WHERE `soundex` LIKE '%s' HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string(soundex($soundex)),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

The above code calculates the distance in miles, if you want the answer in kilometers you need to replace 3959 with 6371.
Then you can use this query to search on soundex field for places within radius.

Comment: Can you explain to me why the query does what it does? ;) It seems kinda complex to me ;)

Comment: mysql-real-escape-string escapes special characters so that isprintft is safe to place it in a mysql_query() see http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for sprintf.see http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf..php all other functions are maths functions